# Java String.split() Regex to split mathematical expression

Tags: java, regex, split, expression

I have a string:

`"a + b - (2.5 * d / 2) < f > g >= h <= (i == j)"`

Currently I've :

```
String[] ops = str.split("\\s*[a-zA-Z]+\\s*");
String[] notops = str.split("\\s*[^a-zA-Z]+\\s*");
String[] res = new String[ops.length+notops.length-1];
for(int i=0; i<res.length; i++) res[i] = i%2==0 ? notops[i/2] : ops[i/2+1];
```

But this doesn't handle brackets. And also it separates out operators and values, but I want single regex which will split above expression like this:

```
[a, +, b, -, (, 2.5, *, d, /, 2, ), <, f, >, g, >=, h, <=, (, i, ==, j, )]
```

Comment: I don't think regex is going to be very useful if you are trying to parse mathematical formulae of any form. Use a parsing library instead... Barring that you could write a tokenizer based on a Character stream..

Comment: This way (simple regex parsing of remotely complex math statements) leads only to madness. Switch to a stack-based postfix (ha!) or define a lexer with ANTLR (or something.)

Comment: I believe @Adam has answered your question, but I hope that you see from the complicated answer that you're using the wrong tool. If you continue down this path, you'll struggle to mentally comprehend your constructions. Try one of the various lexical analyzer tools (ANTLR, Flex, or Ragel), you'll be much happier in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be easier to express as the tokens you're trying to extract rather than a split regex.

```
String input = "-9 + a + b - (2.5 * d / 2) < f > g >= h <= (i == j) && (foo || bar)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?[0-9.]+|[A-Za-z]+|[-+*/()]|==|<=|>=|&&|[|]{2}");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(input);
List<String> actual = new ArrayList<String>();
while (match.find()) {
    actual.add(match.group());
}
System.out.println(actual);
```

This gives you the result you're after

```
[-9, +, a, +, b, -, (, 2.5, *, d, /, 2, ), f, g, >=, h, <=, (, i, ==, j, ), &&, (, foo, ||, bar, )]
```

Comment: Inside a character class, you don't need to escape characters except `-` *(or you can put it at the begining or the end of the character class)*, `^` if it is at the first position and `]` (and some other cases for disambiguation). Special characters loose their meaning and are seen as literals inside a character class. So you can write `([0-9.]+|[A-Za-z]+|==|<=|>=|[-+*/()])` *(don't forget the division)*. Other things: is the capture group really needed? is it possible to reduce `==|<=|>=` and to add the single comparator at the same time `=` `<` `>`?

Comment: Thanks, answer updated, yes, == <= >= could be reduced, but I believe this would harm readability.

Comment: You could write `[=<>]=?`, but if you think that is not readable, keep in mind that it is more performant since it avoids two alternatives.

Comment: And also it should split && and ||

Comment: Answer updated to include undocumented requirements &&, || and negative numbers. Does this solve your problem, is so, please consider accepting answer